# advanced mathematical treatement of revealed preference and utility theory?

Tags: reference-request, utility, expected-utility

I am looking for a textbook that treats revealed preference and utility theory much more thoroughly than does Mas-Collel.

What would be suggestions for this? Specifically I'm interested in conditions under which utility functions are characterized uniquely up to monotonic or linear transformations.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good, thorough book on revealed preference theory. I copied the bibliographic information from my Kindle copy.
Title: Revealed preference theory / Christopher P. Chambers, Federico Echenique. Description: New York : Cambridge University Press, [2016]

Chambers, Christopher P.; Echenique, Federico. Revealed Preference Theory (Econometric Society Monographs) . Cambridge University Press. Kindle Edition.

There is also the 1988 classic by David M. Kreps, Notes on the Theory of Choice (Westview publishers) and the 2013 Microeconomic Foundations I, also by Kreps (Princeton University Press) has quite a thorough discussion.